# vtiger permission denied installation

Tags: plesk, vtiger

I am installing vtiger 6.5 on a plesk server.
I get a 500 error and this errors:

```
    mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /vtigercrm/includes/runtime/Viewer.php on line 67 

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in vtigercrm/includes/runtime/Viewer.php on line 67  

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'unable to write file vtigercrm/includes/runtime/../../test/templates_c/vlayout/wrt581a4659dfbd4' in vtigercrm/libraries/Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php:44 

mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:              
mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 

vtigercrm/libraries/Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(201): Smarty_Internal_Write_File::writeFile('/var/www/vhosts...', '<?php /* Smarty...', Object(Vtiger_Viewer))          

mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 vtigercrm/libraries/Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(155): Smarty_Internal_Template->compileTemplateSource()   

mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 vtigercrm/libraries/Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(374): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('modules/Vtiger/...', NULL, NULL, NULL, true)                

mod_fcgid: stderr: #3 vtigercrm/libraries/Smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 44
```

I tried setting the permission to 775 and chown apache:apache but still it wont work.

Hope anyone can help

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this within a .sh

chmod -R 775 vtigercrm
chown -R :psaserv vtigercrm

Comment: Thanks, Changing the ownership works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this.
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/vtigercrm